# Select2 as list appearance

Tags: css, yii2, jquery-select2

How to change style Select2 in multiple options,
For example, I have choose 4 items.

```
x Green, x Red, x Blue, x Yellow
```

I need something neat looking in my form.
I want to display them like a a list. The goal is

```
x Green 
x Red
x Blue
x Yellow
```

Note, Basically it comes form [Select2 Yii2](http://demosbs3.krajee.com/widget-details/select2).
But, I also can use pure js or jQuery.
[image]
Any help, it so appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Select2 tags are `float: left`, so to achieve this you have to add

```
.select2-container--default li {
  clear: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aj2hsw9c/

Answer (score 1):

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    background-color: unset;
    border: unset;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: default;
    float: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```